# Calculating age with datetime (Python)

Tags: python

I need to calculate someone's date using the datetime module.
This is what I have:

```
from datetime import date as d
date = d.today() #which gives year-month-day
```

Now I want to calculate someone's age up to this day. The year of birth etc has to be inputted. I had this in mind:

```
age = ((d.year() - input1), (d.month() - input2), (d.day()- input3))
```

This gives the following error:

```
TypeError: 'getset_descriptor' object is not callable
```

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: `day, year, month` are not functions.

Comment: Omg lol thanks @AlbinPaul

Comment: Leaving aside that `year`, `month` and `day` are attributes, assuming that `input1`, `input2` and `input3` are year, month and day of birth, should you use some `timedelta` rather than *element by element* subtraction? For example, if birthday is 2020-12-31  and current date is 2021-01-01, what do you achieve with the differences?

Answer (score 2):

`date, year, month` are attributes, not functions.
And you have to use `date.year` instead of `d.year`, as `d` is the imported module and date is the date object contain the current date.

```py
age = ((date.year - input1), (date.month - input2), (date.day - input3))
```